# How do I add a new column to a dataframe after each for loop?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to save a numeric vector that is calculated in a for loop, and then save that into a new column in a dataframe at the end of the for loop.

```
d.dataframe = NULL
for (i in 1:length(viral_raw)) {

  scores <- PWMscoreStartingAt(human.pwm, viral_raw[[i]], starting.at = 1:99)

  d.dataframe$i <-scores
}
```

But right now its overwriting the i'th column everytime

Comment: delete `d.dataframe$i` line and then add `d.dataframe=cbind(d.dataframe,scores)`

Comment: @User7598 that worked beautifully! thanks!

Comment: great - just added as an answer

Comment: Just FYI, `d.dataframe$i <-scores` doesn't overwrite the ith column, it overwrites the column named "i" in each iteration. See the section "Recursive (list-like) objects" in the help file from `help("$")`, although this entire help file is worth a careful read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, you should delete `d.dataframe$i` line and then add `d.dataframe=cbind(d.dataframe,scores)`

The final code will look like:

```
d.dataframe = NULL
for (i in 1:length(viral_raw)) {

  scores <- PWMscoreStartingAt(human.pwm, viral_raw[[i]], starting.at = 1:99)

  d.dataframe=cbind(d.dataframe,scores)
}
```